# how to pass parameters to a callback method when you have used the constrocer to bind it?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am using the way below to do the callback as it's said that it's the most optimized/fast way:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._onClick}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
  _onClick() {
    // Do whatever you like, referencing "this" as appropriate
  }
}
```

but what if I need to pass parameters to my `_onClick` method?
I know how to do it if I used `.bind(this)` as a prop but the way I showed above i dont konw how to handle that.

By the way, i read the article [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) but it does apply to me.

Comment: From where do you want to pass values to where? Just call the function with the respective arguments and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I think these articles would clarify a lot:
[article1](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) and [articles2](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/). You could try this below implementation also, it's inspired from the 2 articles :

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
/*
  in your case you need to make the bind under the render call as below
*/

  _onClick() {
    // Do whatever you like, referencing "this" as appropriate
  }

  render() {
    return (
      /*
          this bind here is necessary to precise the params,
          and about the perfermances issues it's very relative to the app composition.
        */
      <div onClick={this._onClick.bind(this /*,var1, var2*/)}>Hello!</div>
    );
  }
}

// a solution for passing properties without
// entring in perfermances issues is to make a small refacto :

class Foo extends React.Component {
  _onClick() {
    // Do whatever you like, referencing "this" as appropriate
  }
  render() {
    return <MyDiv {...this.props} onItemClick={this._onClick}>Hello!</MyDiv>;
  }
}

const MyDiv = React.createClass({
    render() {
      // Don't need a bind here, since it's just calling
      // our own click handler
      return (
        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Hello!</div>
      );
    },

    handleClick() {
      // Our click handler has access over the this.props,
      // since React.createClass auto bounds this.
      // so it could just pass what it needs along.
      this.props.onItemClick(/*arguments from this.props*/);
    }
  });
```

Comment: hmmm so that way I am again using a fat arrow.  doesn't it create a brand new function on every single render?

Comment: I think this blog could help you, this is the link: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Comment: @farmcommand2, I've updated the answer and i think it could help at least a little, since the topic was confusing and mysterious enough.